# Compare different sized vectors with different values

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, indexing

I'm still fairly new to working with Matlab and programming. I have a dataset with `n` trials, of these (in this case) `m` are relevant. So I have an `m`-by-`1` vector with the indices of the relevant trials (`rel`). I have another vector (`Correct` which is `n`-by-`1`) that consists of `0` and `1`. `n` is always bigger than `m`. I need to know which trials (of the `m`-by-`1` relevant trials) have a `1` in the `n`-by-`1` vector. I have tried `for`-loops but I always get an error `'Index exceeds matrix dimensions.'`

Here is my code:

```
for i=1:length(rel);
    CC=rel(find(Correct==1));
end;
```

I think it should be fairly simple but I don't know yet how to explain to Matlab what I want...

Thank you all for your answers. I realized that my question was not as clear as I thought (also a learning process I guess..) so your suggestions weren't exactly what I need. I'm sorry for being unclear.

1. Correct is not a logical, it does contain 0 and 1 but these refer to correct or incorrect answer (I'm actually not sure if this matters but I thought I let you know)
2. rel is a subset of the original data with all trials (all trials=n trials), Correct is the same length as the original vector with all trials (n trials). So rel contains the indices of the (for me) relevant trials of the original data and is that way connected to Correct.

I hope this makes my question a bit more clear, if not, let me know!

Thank you!

Comment: The question is, if `Correct` is longer than `rel` then how to the rows correspond to each other. Do the elements of `rel` correspond to the first `m` elements of `Correct`? Or does `Correct` contain `m` `1`s in it...?

Comment: rel is a subset of the original data with all trials (with n trials), Correct is the same length as the original vector with all trials (n trials). So rel contains the indices of all relevant trials of the original data...

Comment: @JaMara What is wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear from your question what you are trying to do but I think I have an idea.

You have a vector `n` similar to

```
>> n = round(rand(1, 10))
n =
     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
```

and `m` is indices of this vector similar to

```
>> m = [1 3 7 9];
```

Now we use `m` to index `n` as `n(m)` which will return the values of `n` corresponding to the elements in `m`. Next we need to check these for equality with `1` as `n(m) == 1` and finally we need to figure out what values of `m` have `n` equal to `1` again by indexing. So putting this altogether we get

```
>> m(n(m) == 1)
ans =
     3     7
```

To find the indices of `m` that are being returned you can use

```
>> find(n(m) == 1)
ans =
     2     4
```

Comment: You are totally right, your answer is what I need, sorry! I didn't see that at first... Is there also a way to get the indices of the values of instead of the values themselves?

Comment: @JaMara Check the end of my answer using `find`.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `Correct` is of type `logical` (i.e. it contains trues and falses instead of `0`s and `1`s).

You actually don't need a loop here (this is clear in your case, since you are looping over `i` and never actually use `i` in your loop):

```
m = numel(rel)
CC = rel(Correct(1:m))
```

The reason you are getting that error is because `Correct` has more elements than `rel` so you are attempting to address elements beyond the end of `rel`. I solve this above by only considering the first `m` elements of `Correct`.